# Launching Cmder from Shortcut and executing commands?

Tags: windows, conemu, cmder

So, I am trying to replicate something I do on my Mac where I have a bash script on the desktop that launches the terminal and sshes into a Linux machine for me.  From there I simply type in my password.

I have searched and found out about tasks but that doesn't seem to be exactly what I am looking for.

Basically, I just want to be able to launch Cmder from a shortcut and have it ssh into a box for me.  From there, I will type in the password, etc...

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Tube task is what you need. Configure it and choose startup task.

Comment: @Maximus, What is a Tube task?  Can't find any info searching for that.

Comment: Not a "tube", misprint... [Tasks](http://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html)

Comment: @Maximus ok cool, I will play around with it again and see what I can come up with. It's confusing bc the tasks documentation only shows examples of running other processes/shells and passing arguments to them. I don't see any examples of just running commands in the existing shell like 'ssh user@8.8.8.8'. If I figure this out I am going to write a small tutorial on it!  I was able to do something similar to this using Babun because its shell accepts a command to run as one of its command line args.

Comment: There is almost no sense to run shell if you want to ssh. Ssh.exe is an application you may run anywhere. You may run `sh -c "ssh ..."` if you wish, but what for?

Comment: @Maximus I think I see what you are saying.  You are saying I should use tasks to launch ssh.exe?